# Can i get the push notification's custom properties when the app is closed or background running?

Tags: iphone, notifications, push

1. in iphone,can I get the push notification's custom properties when the app is closed or background running?
2. When an app(not running) received a push, system generate an alert with two buttons: "Close" and "View". If the user taps View, the application is launched. my question is can i change the action of the "View" button, such as open a web link?

Answer (score 1):

1. I'm not sure that understood what you need...
2. Think isn't possible... Only things you can change is button (and body) text. More info you can find [in Table 3.2](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/ApplePushService/ApplePushService.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008194-CH100-SW9). One of the solution could be, to automatically open a web link, when application is launched from push notification.

   - If the action button is tapped, the system launches the application and the application calls its delegate’s application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: method (if implemented); it passes in the notification payload (for remote notifications) or the local-notification object (for local notifications). If the application icon is tapped, the application calls the same method, but furnishes no information about the notification.